# CSS Flex-Box with same height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Can anyone say why the boxes don't get the same height?
I can't find the point.
I want to get three boxes right to each other and all boxes with the same height, no matter what text length.

```css
#article-grid article.et_pb_post {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  line-height: 2em;
  width: 23%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <div id="article-grid" class="et_pb_module">
    <div class="et_pb_ajax_pagination_container">

      <article class="et_pb_post">
        <h2 class="entry-title">BOX 1</h2>
        <div class="post-content">
          <p>BOX1
            <p>
              <p>gfdfjgsdjfgjsgdfjhsgd hfdjkfh sdkh kjhfg jhgds hdskfh sdkh</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <!-- .et_pb_post -->

      <article class="et_pb_post">
        <h2 class="entry-title">BOX 2</h2>
        <div class="post-content">
          <p>BOX2
            <p>
              <p>gfdfjgds hdskfh s dgh fdhg fdkjhgkfdh gklh kfgh fdkdkgfdfjgds hdskfh s dgh fdhg fdkjhgkfdh gklh kfgh fdkdkgfdfjgds hdskfh s dgh fdhg fdkjhgkfdh gklh kfgh fdkdkh</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <!-- .et_pb_post -->

      <article class="et_pb_post">
        <h2 class="entry-title">BOX 3</h2>
        <div class="post-content">
          <p>BOX3
            <p>
              <p>gfdfjgs fdhkgh khlfdkhfd klhg klh khdjfgjsgdfjhsgdjhfg jhgds hdskfh sdkh</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <!-- .et_pb_post -->

      <article class="et_pb_post">
        <h2 class="entry-title">BOX 4</h2>
        <div class="post-content">
          <p>BOX4
            <p>
              <p>gfdfjgsdjfgjsgdfjhsgdjhfg jhgds fgölkglfdgkh fdjklhgdlgkls hdkh kg ugildskfh sdkh</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <!-- .et_pb_post -->

    </div>
    <!-- .et_pb_posts -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- #main-content -->
```

Comment: set display flex on the parent of  your articles. See:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your code you had put **display:flex** into wrong class it should be into your parent div of all Boxes.

```css
#article-grid article.et_pb_post {
/*   display: -webkit-flex; */
/*   display: flex; */
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  line-height: 2em;
  width: 23%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  height: 100%;
}

.et_pb_module {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <div id="article-grid" class="et_pb_module">
    <div class="et_pb_ajax_pagination_container">

      <article class="et_pb_post">
        <h2 class="entry-title">BOX 1</h2>
        <div class="post-content">
          <p>BOX1
            <p>
              <p>gfdfjgsdjfgjsgdfjhsgd hfdjkfh sdkh kjhfg jhgds hdskfh sdkh</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <!-- .et_pb_post -->

      <article class="et_pb_post">
        <h2 class="entry-title">BOX 2</h2>
        <div class="post-content">
          <p>BOX2
            <p>
              <p>gfdfjgds hdskfh s dgh fdhg fdkjhgkfdh gklh kfgh fdkdkgfdfjgds hdskfh s dgh fdhg fdkjhgkfdh gklh kfgh fdkdkgfdfjgds hdskfh s dgh fdhg fdkjhgkfdh gklh kfgh fdkdkh</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <!-- .et_pb_post -->

      <article class="et_pb_post">
        <h2 class="entry-title">BOX 3</h2>
        <div class="post-content">
          <p>BOX3
            <p>
              <p>gfdfjgs fdhkgh khlfdkhfd klhg klh khdjfgjsgdfjhsgdjhfg jhgds hdskfh sdkh</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <!-- .et_pb_post -->

      <article class="et_pb_post">
        <h2 class="entry-title">BOX 4</h2>
        <div class="post-content">
          <p>BOX4
            <p>
              <p>gfdfjgsdjfgjsgdfjhsgdjhfg jhgds fgölkglfdgkh fdjklhgdlgkls hdkh kg ugildskfh sdkh</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <!-- .et_pb_post -->

    </div>
    <!-- .et_pb_posts -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- #main-content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `display:flex` on a common parent. Then each article can also flex in the column direction to stretch into the available vertical space.

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 25%;
}

.articleInner {
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 12px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
  <article>
    <div class="articleInner">
      <p>senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper
        pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="articleInner">
      <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="articleInner">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus
        turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="articleInner">
      <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```